# Slug URL Generator

Tags: php, strings

Just a slug generator. I'm wondering if this can be simplified any further.

Many thanks.

```
<?php
function slug($string) {

    // Replace all non letters, numbers, spaces or hypens
    $string = preg_replace('/[^\-\sa-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', mb_strtolower($string));

    // Replace spaces and duplicate hyphens with a single hypen
    $string = preg_replace('/[\-\s]+/', '-', $string);

    // Trim off left and right hypens
    $string = trim($string, '-');

    return $string;
}

echo slug('-- This is an example     of an ------ article   - @@@ ..,.:~&**%$£%$^*'); // outputs "this-is-an-example-of-an-article"
```

Updated version based on feedback:

```
<?php
function createSlug($slug) {

    $lettersNumbersSpacesHyphens = '/[^\-\s\pN\pL]+/u';
    $spacesDuplicateHypens = '/[\-\s]+/';

    $slug = preg_replace($lettersNumbersSpacesHyphens, '', $slug);
    $slug = preg_replace($spacesDuplicateHypens, '-', $slug);

    $slug = trim($slug, '-');

    return mb_strtolower($slug, 'UTF-8');
}

echo createSlug('-- This is an example ű of an ------ article   - @@@ ..,.%&*£%$&*(*');
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You could create a few explanatory local variables:

   ```
   $lettersNumbersSpacesHypens = '/[^\-\sa-zA-Z0-9]+/';
   $spacesAndDuplicateHyphens = '/[\-\s]+/';
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   $lettersNumbersSpacesHypens = '/[^\-\sa-zA-Z0-9]+/';
   $slug = preg_replace($lettersNumbersSpacesHypens, '', mb_strtolower($slug));

   $spacesAndDuplicateHyphens = '/[\-\s]+/';
   $slug = preg_replace($spacesAndDuplicateHyphens, '-', $slug);
   ```

   These would eliminate the comments. (I haven't checked the regexps, other names might be more appropriate.)

   Reference: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods*, *Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler:

   > Put the result of the expression, or parts of the expression, 
   >   in a temporary variable with a name that explains the purpose.

   And *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*.
2. `slug` could be renamed to `cleanSlug` (contains a verb) to describe what the function does.
3. I'd rename the `$string` variable to `$slug` It would be more descriptive, it would express the intent of the variable.
4. I'd use a whitelist instead of the blacklist. Defining the allowed characters (A-Z, 0-9 etc) would create proper URLs from URLs which contain special characters like `é` or `ű`.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my original question with some changes. Didn't notice the problem with different characters before, this has now been fixed.

Comment: @AlexGarrett: You're welcome. I've updated the answer a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small extension to what has been written. If your slug generator is not for an assignment but for actual deployment a lot of frameworks use slug helpers already. I use Laravel, however Laravel has an entire class so that might be messy.

Before Laravel, Codeigniter was the rapid deploy system and their slug system is pretty robust.

Take a look at the slug file. Now mind you they have formatted it into a class with a lot of comments - but if you omit everything you can compare their's and yours and see where the middle ground can be.

[Codeigniter Slug Class](https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Slug-Library/blob/master/Slug.php)

Note - I'm adding this extra bit because as always you shouldn't re-engineer code if its been done and done well.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice. I actually adapted this code from the Laravel framework. It's for education purposes, so wanted to simplify it so it's easier for beginners to grasp. But I completely agree, good hardened code shouldn't be rewritten if not necessary.

Comment: I recommend the codeigniter's version instead because i had to reverse engineer it for legacy non MVC code and it works better as as stand-alone function rather than a class (once you take out the clutter)